# ASP.NET How to know if control in page if-else is visible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

Here is an example. The problem is that the Label2 has always Visible=true, regardless of the if-else result. How can i know if its visible or not?

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gdv">
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>

  <%if (!IsItem)
                  {%>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Qtde") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <%}
                  else
                  { %>
                  <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Qtde") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <%} %>


                </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

I cannot access IsItem, since the class where i want to check the label for visibility is not the page code-behind. Also these controls are in a gridview.

The class method that checks for visibility is not called directly by the page, its a private method of a server control that extends a grid view and is supposed to work with a varierty of cases.

Thanks.

EDIT------------
I have found an alternative, decent solution. Still, i'm curious to know if it's possible to do the aforementioned. Thanks you for your time,

Comment: `if (!IsItem)` apparently tells you.

Comment: I cannot access IsItem property, i added edits to clarify this.

Comment: It's hard to see what the problem is. What determines the state if not isitem?

Comment: It depends on each row, sometimes the row is an item, sometimes it isn't. The page sets this viewstate property on the edit event.

Answer (score 0):

You are displaying that Label based on a variable called "IsItem." Why can't you use that to determine the Label's visibility?

Comment: I want to know it in a class different from the page code-behind, so i cant access IsItem property

Comment: Pass IsItem as a bool parameter to a method in the other class.

Comment: The class method that checks for visibility is not called directly by the page, its a private method of a server control that extends a grid view and is supposed to work with a varierty of cases.